# Protocol used by nutch

Tags: protocols, nutch, charles-proxy

Can somebody please tell me which protocol is used by nutch for fetching pages.
I wanted to check what kind of request does nutch makes ?

I used charles proxy to see the request information but sadly nothing obtained there.
Am i missing something about charles proxy or about nutch ??

I have also tried wireshark but there cam too many packets and I could not identify which one was of nutch ?

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Nutch is a web crawler, so I guess it is using HTTP protocol. Most likely **HTTP GET** to fetch pages.

If you need more information (e. g. user agend of nutch) consider setting up a apache web server on your machine and crawl some test pages. Then have a look at the apache access log.

Comment: I tried crawling some other website and then tried to find out the result in charles. Charles was showing all other requests but not a single request from nutch. i could not understand the reason.

Comment: Have you nutch set up to use a proxy? Have a look at the corresponding lines of the `nutch-site.xml`: [behind this link](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/SetupProxyForNutch#Configure_Nutch_.28Nutch_1.3.29)